# I want to send message to facebook friends to their message box for android

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, message

I am developing app that has facebook message sending feature.
Through facebbook login i want to send my friend a message not a wall post, i want the to send message not a wall post or anything else. There is a kind of XMPP used as far i know please provide some solution.

Kindly suggest the solution, its urgent.

Thanks
Gopal

Answer (score 0):

First of all Edit your SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism class . Copy and paste this code .

```
package com.facebook.android;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.sasl.Sasl;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.Base64;

import android.util.Log;


public class SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism extends SASLMechanism {

    private static final String NAME              = "X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM";

    private String              apiKey            = "";
    private String              accessToken        = "";

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
        super(saslAuthentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException {
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new AuthMechanism(NAME, ""));
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String apiKey, String host, String accessToken) throws IOException, XMPPException {
        if (apiKey == null || accessToken == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameters");
        }

        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.hostname = host;

        String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, this);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String username, String host, CallbackHandler cbh) throws IOException, XMPPException {
        String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, cbh);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void challengeReceived(String challenge) throws IOException {
        byte[] response = null;

        if (challenge != null) {
            String decodedChallenge = new String(Base64.decode(challenge));
            Map<String, String> parameters = getQueryMap(decodedChallenge);

            String version = "1.0";
            String nonce = parameters.get("nonce");
            String method = parameters.get("method");

            String composedResponse =
                "method=" + URLEncoder.encode(method, "utf-8") +
                        "&nonce=" + URLEncoder.encode(nonce, "utf-8") +
                        "&access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(accessToken, "utf-8") +
                        "&api_key=" + URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "utf-8") +
                        "&call_id=0" +
                        "&v=" + URLEncoder.encode(version, "utf-8");
            response = composedResponse.getBytes();
        }

        String authenticationText = "";

        if (response != null) {
            authenticationText = Base64.encodeBytes(response);
        }

        // Send the authentication to the server
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new Response(authenticationText));
    }

    private Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String[] params = query.split("\\&");

        for (String param : params) {
            String[] fields = param.split("=", 2);
            map.put(fields[0], (fields.length > 1 ? fields[1] : null));
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

Then use this method to login to facebook

```
private void LoginToFaceBook(){
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
        xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
        SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM",SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAppId());
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        try {
            xmpp.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Connected to " + xmpp.getHost());

        } catch (XMPPException e1) {
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Unable to " + xmpp.getHost());

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            xmpp.login(PreferenceConnector.APP_ID, mFacebook.getAccessToken());




        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
```

Once you are done with log in . Use this link to get Roster and sending a message .

http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code! I've been trying to get this working for a while now, would you be willing to share your project files so I can take a look at a working facebook messaging app that using xmpp. Or even just the other files associated with facebook messaging. I have an open question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079632/facebook-asmack-xmpp-client-returns-random-numbers-for-roster that I would be more than happy to reward you the bounty for if you can help me, Thanks!

Comment: I'll check it out and give it a try now, ill let you know

Comment: @JanshairKhan I have a problem with you code and new 3.3.0 version of Smack. Did you adopt your code for Smack update?

Comment: Please share the error . I've not worked on it for a long time .