# Facebook asmack xmpp client returns random numbers for roster

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, asmack

I followed the guidlines given in the following SO question to connect to facebook chat using xmpp and I am able to connect to facebook and pull the correct number of contacts but when it prints the contacts they are all random numbers @chat.facebook.com and all return offline.

[Android Facebook chat example project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946508/android-facebook-chat-example-project/11238124#11238124)

```
public void connectToFb() throws XMPPException {

        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required);
        config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
        config.setTruststorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
        config.setTruststorePassword("changeit");
        config.setTruststoreType("bks");
        config.setSendPresence(false);
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(null, MemorizingTrustManager.getInstanceList(this), new java.security.SecureRandom());
            config.setCustomSSLContext(sc);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Unable to use MemorizingTrustManager", e);
        }
        XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
        try {
            xmpp.connect();
            xmpp.login("user.name", "password"); // Here you have to used only facebookusername from facebookusername@chat.facebook.com
            Roster roster = xmpp.getRoster();
            Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
            System.out.println("Connected!");
            System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
            // shows first time onliners---->
            String temp[] = new String[50];
            int i = 0;
            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                String user = entry.getUser();
                Log.i("TAG", user);
            }
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            xmpp.disconnect();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to readable name, so try using

```
rosterEntry.getName()
```

which returns the users name, instead of

```
rosterEntry.getUser()
```

which returns the JID.

Not sure about your offline problem though.  How are you checking?  You have to set up a [roster listener](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/roster.html) to get changes in presence.

Comment: I did that and it worked thank you, but now when i try to check if they user is online it always returns that they are offline and i am unable to send anyone messages...

Comment: Using .getPresence on the JID or the name. How would i go about sending messages?

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug in XMPP library . There is a work around for that .

**Step 1:** Connect to XMPP.

**Step 2:** Login to facebook account through xmpp.

**Step 3:** get online friend list using this fql query .

```
    SELECT uid, name, online_presence ,
      sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Then i concat address with string **uid@chat.facebook.com**  and communicate via XMPP.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I updated my question with my current code, where would I insert that code?

Comment: after loging how to get these uid,with the using of uid and how could i get those things

Comment: uid is user id of a friend in your friend list.

Answer (score 0):

(It's not 100% clear what problem you're having regarding the online/offline thing may be a bug or something you're doing incorrectly), but you won't get back the user's actual user IDs in the response, this is mentioned in the docs:

`The user's own Jabber ID (JID) is different from the Jabber ID that their contacts will see because the translation is done internally.`

Comment: Then how would one go about building a xmpp chat client for facebook?

Comment: I'm not sure why that would prevent you building a client (note: i'm referring to the JIDs, you *should* be able to get presence information as far as i know)